# How to store a user's records in a variable and then filter them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Rails app I have `users` which can have many `invoices` which in turn can have many `payments`.

In my dashboard view I have a summary of all the `payments` that the user has received so far, either summed up by **month**, by **quarter** or by **year**.

Since switching between those 3 modes should be straightforward and fast, I figured that it would be a good idea to *not* use scopes here but instead store all the user's payments in a variable and filter that variable depending on what mode the user selects (month, quarter, or year).

In addition to that there's also a separation into **gross**, **net**, and **taxable** amounts.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :user

  def net_amount
    invoice.subtotal * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end  

  def taxable_amount
    invoice.total_tax * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end

  def gross_amount
    invoice.total * percent_of_invoice_total / 100
  end

  def self.sum_within_range(range, kind)
    @sum ||= includes(:invoice => :items)
    @sum.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&:"#{kind}_amount")
  end

end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :invoices
  has_many  :payments

  def revenue_between(range, kind)
    payments.sum_within_range(range, kind)
  end

end
```

At first glance this works but when a user edits one of his `payment` records, the instance variable `@sum` does not get reloaded.

How can this be achieved?

Maybe there's an alternative / better approach to solve this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class level variable which stored information about when to update the sum. This is a (probably) non-functional example, which should show how it works.

```
class Payment
  after_save :update_sum

  @@update = {}

  def update_sum
    @@update[user] = true
  end

  def sum
    @sum = includes(invoice: :items) if @@update[user] || !@sum
    @sum.select { |x| range.cover? x.date }.sum(&:"#{kind}_amount")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I was unable to get this to work, though. I keep getting this error: `uninitialized class variable @@update in Payment`

Comment: OK, thanks. That error is fixed now. But it is complaining about an `undefined method 'user'` in this line now: `@sum ||= includes(:invoice => :items) if @@update[user] || !@sum`. Sorry, I am still new to Rails. Maybe I am missing something really fundamental here.

Comment: This is actually more of a Ruby question than rails. I put user in as a placeholder value. What you need to do is have a `user` method so that each `Payment` object can find out which user created it. Then that `user` line will call the `user` method.

Comment: OK. I have a column `user_id` in each `payment` record. Won't that suffice? But I am not sure how to go from there... I am new to both Rails **and** Ruby by the way :-)

Comment: That will work. Do you have your `belongs_to` relationship set up?

Comment: Yes, sure. I even tried to provide some details in my OP above.

Comment: You would need to pass user into the function since it is static.